# How to remove a specific letter within the word of each line of a file

Tags: sed

I need to remove a character after a number in each line. How can I do the job by using sed?
I used sed command to remove but failed.

Input:

```
481065919|g UPF0114
481065919|g PRK12772
```

I need to remove `|g` from each line.

Expected output:

```
481065919 UPF0114
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can also be done with `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/\|g/,"")}8' file
```

`gsub` replace anything found between `/.../`
To find `|g` you need to escape the `|` since its a special character, so `\|g`
Replace with `""`, means nothing (same as delete)
`8` is just any positive number, do default action, print anything.
`8` does the same as `1` and the same as `1 {print}` and the same as `1 {print $0}`

Answer (score 1):

Removing is the same as replacing with nothing. This works for me:

```
sed -i "s/|5//g" test.txt
```

Comment: Sorry with this command I am not getting result. Error:No such file? I think problem with last '/'symbol.

Comment: It's a bit tricky because of the pipe symbol, but with the line from my updated answer it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry again. Not worked.I am getting empty output file,

Comment: Strange... I created a test file with your exact content from your question above and the statement given in my answer works flawlessly. You noticed the double quotes, did you?

Comment: Yep the same command I used.I just copied into terminal. I am using zsh shell. This may b reason?